# No consigo entrar en el for

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

estoy haciendo un metodo para cargar una lista de datos en jsf 2, soy bastante nuevo en esto, consigo cargar los datos a la hora de buscarlos, pero a la hora de entrar al for me lleva al return directamente y no consigo mostrarlos en la web. Codigo:

```
public List<SelectItem> getAllEmpresas() {
    LazyGenericDataModel<EmpresaDTO> em = empcon.getListaDatos();
    selectEmpresa = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    int x = 0;
    for (EmpresaDTO emp : em) {
        selectEmpresa.add(new SelectItem(x, emp.getNombre()));
        x++;
    }

    return selectEmpresa;

}
```

y el jsf:

```
            <h:selectOneMenu id="combo" value="#{p002ProyectoController.empresaSeleccionada}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecciona empresa"  noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{p002ProyectoController.allEmpresas}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Si no te entra en el for es porque en em no tienes empresas, el array está vacío.

Comment: Definitivamente no me carga el array, pero el getListaDatos se que me funciona, lo uso para cargar una tabla también, mirare o probare a hacer otro método. Gracias.

Comment: Es posible que getListaDatos se te ejecute de manera asíncrona? si es así, podría pasar que llegue antes al for que lo que le cuesta devolver la llamada a esa función pero sin ver más código no puedo asegurar nada.